# Python pandas: Why does df.iloc[:, :-1].values for my training data select till only the second last column?

Tags: python, pandas

Very simply put,

For the same training data frame `df`, when I use 
`X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values`, it will select till the second last column of the data frame instead of the last column (which is what I want BUT it's a strange behavior I've never seen before), and I know this as the second last column's value and the last column's value for that row is different.

However, using 
`y = df.iloc[:, -1].values` gives me the row vector of the last column's values which is exactly what I want.

Why is the negative 1 for X giving me the second last column's value instead?

[image: Error]

Comment: up until the last column but not including the last column, since python ranges / slices do not include the end point...  I do not understand what you are expecting instead...

Comment: like, `data = [1,2,3,4,5]` then a slice up to the last element `data[:-1] -> [1,2,3,4]` would remove the last one because the end point is the last element and slices never include the endpoint... This is exactly the intended behaviour.

Comment: `df.iloc[:, 2]` selects the second column but `df.iloc[:, :2]` or explicitly `df.iloc[:, 0:2]` selects the columns until (excluding) the second column. It's the same as Python's slices. When you use a negative index, nothing changes. If you say `df.iloc[:, -1]` it means the last column, but `df.iloc[:, :-1]` means until the last column.

Comment: Oh yes I see...I misunderstood -1 as always selecting the last column.

Comment: @leeks50996 `-1` indice **does** always mean "last element" but in slices the endpoint is excluded.  This is the same behaviour for positive indices for example:  `data = "abcde"` indice `2` refers to `"c"` and `data[:2]` will be everything up to but not including `c` so `data[:2] -> "ab"`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you have only two columns in `df`, because if there is more columns, [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) select all columns without last:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

print(df.iloc[:, :-1])
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  4  7  1  5
1  2  5  8  3  3
2  3  6  9  5  6

X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
print (X)
[[1 4 7 1 5]
 [2 5 8 3 3]
 [3 6 9 5 6]]

print (X.shape)
(3, 5)
```

Comment: That's strange, because my df originally has 24 columns as displayed in df.shape (printed in the screenshot).

Comment: And what return `print df.columns` ?

Comment: It gives me an array of [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,  17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], as I read df with header = None

Comment: Hmm, but screenshot return `X.shape = (670294, 23)` it means all columns without last.

Comment: hmm yes I just realised the -1 doesn't always mean 'the last column'; in the context of slices it actually means 'until before the last column'.

Answer (score 5):

Just for clarity

[With respect to python syntax, this question has been answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2336654)

Python list slicing syntax states that for `a:b` it will get `a` and everything upto but not including `b`.  `a:` will get `a` and everything after it.  `:b` will get everything before `b` but not `b`.  The list index of `-1` refers to the last element.  `:-1` adheres to the same standards as above in that this gets everything before the last element but not the last element.  If you want the last element included use `:`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you learn something from this

```
# Single selections using iloc and DataFrame
# Rows:
data.iloc[0] # first row of data frame (Aleshia Tomkiewicz) - Note a Series data type output.
data.iloc[1] # second row of data frame (Evan Zigomalas)
data.iloc[-1] # last row of data frame (Mi Richan)
# Columns:
data.iloc[:,0] # first column of data frame (first_name)
data.iloc[:,1] # second column of data frame (last_name)
data.iloc[:,-1] # last column of data frame (id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Bcz Upper bound is exclusive. Its similar to slicing a list:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]

a[:3]
```

will result in [1, 2, 3]. It did not take the last element.

Answer (score 0):

*Consider list l containing the following elements:*

Index  0  1  2  3  4  5

Values a  b  c  d  e  f

Index -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1

*if you print :*

l[:]--> a b c d e f

*But for*

l[:-1]-->a b c d e

*This happens because in:*

l[:]-->l[start : end]--> default value start=0 end=6

l[:-1]-->l[start : end]--> default value start=0 end=-1

Considering negative indexing you will get:

l[:-1]-->a b c d e

*It will include start and exclude end while printing*